# Add Hoc Workflow in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

Sorry I'm new in Sharepoint 2016 for searching a feature.

Is that Sharepoint 2016 have a feature supports ad hoc workflows? Ad hoc workflows are used for more dynamic processing flows such as exception handling with a right mouse click and able to see the workflow history.

If sharepoint has that feature. I will propose that Sharepoint to our company.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it’s feasible to create State Machine Workflows in Visual Studio.

[Creating SharePoint 2010 State Machine Workflows in Visual Studio 2010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg508985(v=office.14))

In SharePoint 2016 OOB workflow and SharePoint Designer workflow, we are not able to generate dynamic flow.